# Set project name as a parameter in Django when using git

Tags: python, django, git, github, django-cms

I have a **Djangocms** application and I'd like to have the name of the project given as an input from terminal when I'm cloning it from **github**.

**Flow:**

I'd like something like this:

`git clone git-link --project_name` where `project_name` will be the parameter that will store the name of my project. Is this even achievable ? Or is there another way of doing it ?

> e.g: `git clone some-project --website5` should create a project named
>   `website5` instead of `website` (in this project case)

---

I will post here my project structure and how some of the important files look like:

[image]

I'd like website to be something like `{{ project_name }}` but I don't know how to handle the parameter flow.

**manage.py**

```
...
from {{ project_name }} import get_project_root_path, import_env_vars
...
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "{{ project_name }}.settings.development")
```

**wsgi.py**

```
from {{ project_name }} import get_project_root_path, import_env_vars
...
```

**base.py**

```
...
WSGI_APPLICATION = '{{ project_name }}.wsgi.application'
...
PROJECT_DIRNAME = '{{ project_name }}'
...
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '{{ project_name }}', 'templates'),
)
...
```

I found something simillar [here](https://github.com/liip/djangocms-template) but I don't know where he's handling the git parameter thing.

Could anyone please explain me in detail how can one achieve this and what dependencies / files shall I install / modify ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your linked Git project, the template engine of `startproject` is used, as documented [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/django-admin/#startproject-projectname-destination).

For your usecase, you can easily use the same technique, because GitHub provides your current repository as zip file, which can be used as template for the `startproject` command.

```
$ django-admin startproject --template=https://github.com/your_user_name/your_repository_name/archive/development.zip [projectname]
```

This will use the *development* branch of `your_repository_name` as template for creating a new project.

Comment: so I don't have to rename `website` to `{{ project_name }}` as I did, right ?

Comment: You may have a look at [my project-template](https://github.com/Mischback/django-project-skeleton). In fact, that folder is named `project_name`.

Comment: can you tell me in [my project](https://github.com/MrGrj1010/djangocms-template), how should I run `django-admin.py startproject --template=..` command ? Ignore the `README.md` file as it is not updated yet.

Comment: Come on, have a look at my answer, it's already there: `django-admin startproject --template=https://github.com/MrGfj1010/djangocms-template/archive/master.zip [projectname]` Please note, your current repository is not yet fully set up for templating.

Comment: why isn't my repository not fully set up for templating ? What's missing from here ?